# Combining in a row results from two tab

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a mysql query that should get only one row result from two tables.

I have a table called users and a table called users_sports.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 71
SELECT user_sport_sport FROM users.sports WHERE user_sport_user = 71
```

I would need a query result in only one row that has all users values from table users and all user_sport_sport values for a specific user.

For example: `id=71, username="mike2"...sport1="Basketball",sport2="Soccer".`

EDIT tb_user_sports

[image]

Table users

[image]

Table tb_sports

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group_concat to fetch all the sports for that user id

```
select u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(ts.sport_name) sports from users u
join tb_user_sports tus ON tus.user_sport_user = u.id
left join tb_sports ts ON ts.id_sport = tus.user_sport_sport
where u.id = 72
group by u.id
```

Source:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

For alias: [link1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) and [link2](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/)